# CodelineIndex from doc package: sorting page vs codeline index entries

Tags: indexing, makeindex, doc

In the following sample "documentation" of a macro `\foo` using the `doc` package, index entries for `\foo` are in an unnatural order.  How can this be avoided?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\DescribeMacro\foo
\lipsum
    \begin{macrocode}
first line of code using \foo
second line of code using \foo
third line of code using \foo
%    \end{macrocode}
\PrintIndex
\end{document}
```

As expected from the documentation of `\CodelineIndex`, we get four index entries in the `.idx` file: the first entry comes from the `\DescribeMacro` on page 2, while the other three are referring to code line numbers later in the document.

```
\indexentry{foo=\verb!*+\foo+|usage}{2}
\indexentry{foo=\verb!*+\foo+}{1}
\indexentry{foo=\verb!*+\foo+}{2}
\indexentry{foo=\verb!*+\foo+}{3}
```

Running `makeindex -s gind.ist test.idx` gives the following `ind` file

```
 \begin{theindex} 
 \makeatletter\scan@allowedfalse
{\bfseries\hfil F\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item \verb*+\foo+\pfill 1, 2, \usage{2}, 3

 \end{theindex}
```

in which one sees that the page reference `\usage{2}` ends up in the middle of the codeline references.  Relatedly, the `makeindex` log file `.ilg` includes a warning about the collision between the `\usage{2}` and the codeline 2.

```
## Warning (input = test.idx, line = 1; output = test.ind, line = 6):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.
```

---

Of course, `doc` is passing codeline numbers and page numbers in the same way to `makeindex`, so `makeindex` has no way to distinguish them and order them well.  I see two ugly ways out, but I'm hoping there is a better way:

- shift all codeline numbers by 1000000 before passing them to `makeindex`, and shift them back when typesetting
- redefine `\item` (or `\pfill`?) in the `theindex` environment to parse the list of pages and codelines and reorder it on the TeX side

Comment: Easier, way to fix it is to redefine DescribeMacro, try `index{Package Commands>\string\foo}` and see if you happy with the results.

Personally, I never liked automatic "indexing", however, brilliant it is.

Answer (score 2):

The following code seems to do the trick.  `makeindex` has rules for sorting composite page numbers of the form A-B-C etc, where A,B,C can be arabic, roman numerals, or latin letters.  I decided to prefix code lines by `A-` (see `A-\number\c@CodelineNo` in the code below) so that they would be sorted separately by `makeindex` (and sorted after the page references, as it turns out).  Then some more code is needed to avoid typesetting `A-`: the idea is to add an encap `\codeline@typeset` to every codeline index entry, while keeping the original encap.

Running `pdflatex test ; makeindex -s gind.ist test ; pdflatex test ; pdflatex test` on the following file yields an index entry for `\foo` that reads `\emph{3}, 1--3, \underline{4}, 7--9`, corresponding to a reference to page 3, a range of references to lines 1-3, a "main" reference to code line 4 (corresponding to the `macro` environment), and another range of lines.  I also included simpler code for the case where `hypdoc` is loaded; however codeline ranges are then not found.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hypdoc}
  {
    \def\codeline@wrindex#1{%
      \if@filesw
      \immediate\write\@indexfile
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{A-\number\c@CodelineNo}}\fi
    }
    \def\hdclindex#1#2#3{%
      \csname\ifx\\#2\\relax\else#2\fi\endcsname{%
        \hyperlink{HD.#1}{\codeline@removeA #3\@gobble A-}%
        \HD@savedest@add{#1}%
      }%
    }
  }
  {
    \def\codeline@wrindex#1{%
      \codeline@wrindex@tweak\empty#1\encapchar\encapchar\@nil
    }
    \def\codeline@wrindex@tweak #1\encapchar#2\encapchar#3\@nil{%
      \codeline@wrindex@do{#1\encapchar codeline@typeset{#2}}%
    }
    \def\codeline@wrindex@do#1{%
      \if@filesw
      \immediate\write\@indexfile
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{A-\number\c@CodelineNo}}\fi
    }
    \def\codeline@typeset#1#2{%
      \csname\ifx\\#1\\relax\else #1\fi\endcsname
      {\codeline@removeA #2\@gobble A-}%
    }
  }
\def\codeline@removeA#1A-{#1\codeline@removeA}
\makeatother
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}

Early on
    \begin{macrocode}
first line of code using \foo
second line of code using \foo
third line of code using \foo
%    \end{macrocode}

\lipsum[1-10]
\DescribeMacro\foo
\lipsum
\begin{macro}{\foo}
    \begin{macrocode}
first line
second line
using \foo not index because we're inside begin{macro}{\foo}...
%    \end{macrocode}
\end{macro}

Later on
    \begin{macrocode}
first line of code using \foo
second line of code using \foo
third line of code using \foo
%    \end{macrocode}

\PrintIndex
\end{document}
```